# Phonetics to English Text?

Tags: phonetics

any site (or application) you can recommend to convert phonetic transcription to regular English text?
Most sites offer the other way.
Thanks!

Comment: There's a reason why.

Comment: You could take a look at the answers to this question: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3378/does-an-ipa-to-english-translator-exist (no app like this found, but You may find the information there useful).

Comment: @jlawler, what reason are *you* thinking of? My reasons are that (a) nobody cares and (b) I don't know how to do a "close enough" search.

Comment: @user6726: The reason is that phonetic transcription is variable, depending on transcriber and context, and that, since English spelling doesn't represent English speech, there is no really good way to match transcription to spelling.

Comment: @jlawler, that is where "close enough" search technology comes into play. E.g. "spelling" differences like [e:, ei, eɪ, ɛɪ, ɛj] and data differences like [rɑʔn̩, rɑɾn̩, rɑtn̩]. We can use the CMU dict. to get the spelling, and phonetically-informed rule-based sloppy-search to map a user's transcription to the CMU transcription.